# CSS Media usage

Tags: css, media-queries

I have two style sheet where I chose one to load depending on the screen width.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 810px), only screen and (min-device-width: 810px)" href="/style/desktop.css" id="platformDependentStyle"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="only screen and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (max-device-width: 800px)" href="/style/mobile.css" />
```

From what I can understand the first style sheet is loaded when the minimum screen width is at least 810px, and the second one is loaded when the maximun screen screen width is 800px at the most. In my style sheet I have this in there

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 810px), only screen and (min-device-width: 810px){
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px), only screen and (max-device-width: 800px){
```

I assume that I am correct but obviously not. For some reason the styling from the 810px is being applied when it should not. Am I missing something fundamental?

Comment: Do you have a viewport set?

Comment: A what?, ok let me google that

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Oh dang how did I miss that

Comment: Both stylesheets are *loaded*, but only one is used. Depending on the case.